# Install PHP 8.0 Yaml extension on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, php

I wrote a simple php based on the fisrt example.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.yaml-parse.php

I got...

```bash
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse() in /var/www/html/p.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/p.php on line 33
```

I use ondrej repository to install php.

```
root@hidra:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
```

There is no package to install yaml extension.

```bash
apt-file search phpize
apt-file search php8.0-yaml
apt-file search php8.2-yaml
```

Ok, let's try to compile it with phpize.

There is not phpize either or php8.0-dev (In debian phpize ussualy is there)

```
root@hidra:~# apt-get install php8.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.0-dev'
```

I tried with Ubuntu 22.04 too. The ondrej have no php8.x-dev php8.x-yaml. And php-dev o php-yaml try to install php7.2 versions.

Besides, ymal code on PECL requires php 7.

What would be the proper way to install it in these circumstances?

I have used https://github.com/dallgoot/yaml to solve it, but I have curiosity with this issue.

Comment: `dpkg -l` only lists already installed packages. Use `apt search` to find packages in repositories.

Comment: @jordanm, You are wrong. dpkg mark installed packages with a colum with the value ii. Not instaled packages have un in that colum. Anyway, I tried apt-file search phpize and more.

Comment: Unless you have paid for Ubuntu Pro, your release is past end-of-life. If you had posted on Ask Ubuntu the question would have been closed. You might try upgrading to a supported release and then running your installs.

Comment: @doneal24, using ondrej repo I'm protected from that. Besides, it's happening into a Ubuntu 22.04 too.

Comment: @icalvete please [edit] your question to include all that info (`apt-file search`, Ubuntu 22.04). Didn’t you find `php8.1-yaml` in 22.04?

Comment: And jordanm is right, you can’t use `dpkg -l` in this manner — it only knows about installed packages and a small subset of available packages. `apt search 'php.*-yaml'` is the appropriate tool here.

Comment: @stephen-kitt. anyway, I used apt-file search

Comment: @icalvete it’s `apt search`, not `apt-file search`. The latter looks for files inside packages (so it’s useful to look for `phpize`), the former searches package metadata (so it’s useful to look for PHP YAML packages).

Comment: By using the ondrej repo you have kept php up to date. How are you handling any new security issues on the dozens-to-hundreds other packages you have installed on the Ubunty 18.04 system?

Answer (score 0):

Install the YAML Extension: The yaml_parse() function is provided by a PHP extension which is not enabled by default. You need to install and enable the YAML extension for PHP.

On a Debian-based system (like Ubuntu), you can usually install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-yaml
```

OR

```
sudo pecl install yaml
```

After installing, you need to enable the extension by adding the following line to your php.ini file:

```
extension=yaml.so
```

**Restart the Web Server**

Comment: kristtof-v88, Ubuntu 18.04 does no have php8. So I used the ondrej repo ( https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php ) php-yaml is a metapackage and try to install php7 version.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 18.04 is no longer in standard support](https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support), so Ondřej Surý stopped providing packages for it ([as explained in his FAQ](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#ubuntu-1)).

I don’t think there is a nice, packaged way to address this at this point on Ubuntu 18.04.

On Ubuntu 22.04, `php8.1-yaml` is available [in the Ubuntu repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-yaml), there’s no need for additional PPAs.